# Retrieving the http headers AND a string value in Angular 17 from a server response

Tags: c#, angular, http-headers

First off I'm still in a learning phase of client/server development, so this might possibly be an easy question for a more experienced developer. Please see what I'm attempting to do below:

This is my post in my client's service that successfully hits my endpoint on my API server, performs its functions, then returns a string token:

```
public login(user: User): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.userUrl + "/login", user, { observe: 'response' })
    .pipe(map(resp => { return resp.headers }));
}
```

I want to update the cookies on the client side since I will need them for future calls (cookies in particular that the server generated). I also need the string token value, but I'm a little confused how to return the headers along with a single value back to my component's function in the client:

```
public login(user: User) {
    this.authService.login(user).subscribe((resp) => {
      localStorage.setItem('authToken', resp);
      if (resp != null) {
        console.log("User logged in successfully!");
        this.router.navigate(['/groceries/'])
      }
    });
}
```

This is the error in my Developer Tools:

```
error
: 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'e', "eyJhbGciOi"... is not valid JSON at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad........
: 
"Unexpected token 'e', \"eyJhbGciOi\"... is not valid JSON"
stack
: 
"SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'e', \"eyJhbGciOi\"... is not valid JSON\n    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)\n
```

However, I can see the value that I want to store as a variable under the Network > Response tabs. So I know that it's coming through, just with that Console error displayed above.

I tried to search for this exact scenario online for a while now, but I know I'm doing something wrong since this scenario doesn't appear to exist!

Comment: Update: I am now returning a serialized model over from my server, and can see the following when I print a console.log:

`{Jwt: 'eyJhbGciOiJody8yMDAxLzA0L3htbG…_5ByJaFPsvaua8QA6uQccXUyLmMS1IQ6sUggOg'}`

Just trying to figre out now how to grab the value.... I've been trying things like indexes on the response, the key name etc, still no luck!